# How to correctly write a type definition where a method returns a class of a specific type that can be instantiated?

Tags: typescript, embind

While trying to write type definitions for embind, specifically the [`extend`](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html#extend-example) feature, I encountered a problem I cannot solve myself. What I have so far is this:

```js
export declare class Deletable {
    public delete(): void;
}

type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

export declare class Extendable extends Deletable {
    public static extend<T extends Constructor<T>>(name: string, o: unknown): new (...args: ConstructorParameters<T>) => T;
    public static implement<T>(o: object): T;
}

class Lexer extends Extendable {
    public constructor(i?: number) { super(); }
}

const WhiteboxLexerTrampoline = Lexer.extend<Lexer>("Lexer", {
});
```

Playground code is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AYwDYEMrDm9BnPOAEWFWBnQCMy4BvAKDibjAFdqBLZRU84ACgCUALjgA3CBwQBuegF969GAE8w2AMIQAdnhhRWyGNAA8AFQB8cALxwtwAO5x%20AOleYA5nlHotygNoAuoLWlqay9KCQsDy4WDgYBHAAoiAwwFoIVDSgaRmEJGQU1NgMzCzsqFxwuugwVTnpCGZwDXlwmjp6BkZQZubm-FroALbAorpQHFruADRwEKKsWgDWWhD2WiK2Dk6uzh5e7doT3dAACpgjfFB4fcFWobJlbJzcNXXcHMNgZKNaMH1%20At5pQAFYoGBbMLyRS4RIAGVAwCgLVSjUIKVymWKdEYzBelW4yGOXUM0H4HAA-KItKxhpRkcFaNVWGooEJpHAFAp6MTOnAAOoACw4aUoEBAiJAyNMUBGkEqdmscClyOcrSaqqgAwARFqdXMGHJBOEgA). The error is on the line with `Lexer.extend<Lexer>()`:

> Type 'Lexer' does not satisfy the constraint 'Constructor'.
> Type 'Lexer' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any[]): Lexer'.(2344)

Obviously I'm missing something related to the constructor parameters. How would this have to be written correctly?

Further information: the class returned from `extend` is used to derive a class from, to be used in my application, like:

```js
export default class WhiteboxLexer extends WhiteboxLexerTrampoline {
    // actual implementation of the lexer.
}
```

Comment: Use `typeof Lexer`: https://tsplay.dev/mMO8lw

Comment: Do you want to tag this with "embind" if the question depends on it?  Or do you want to remove the apparent dependency by describing explicitly what `extend` is supposed to do in the question itself (and not just as an external link)?  Either way: you don't want `T extends Constructor<T>` unless `T` is going to be one of those rare self-constructing constructors, like a factory that makes other factories.  The specific fix depends on what `extend` is supposed to be doing.

Comment: @kelsny The error is clear and I also thought about just using `typeof Lexer`, but seriously, how can this be accepted? The documentation clearly says the `typeof` operator can only be used on identifiers (variables) and members. What is the "type of a type"?. Makes no sense. Additionally, I cannot use such a  type in all contexts, where I could if it was just a class, not `typeof AClass`.

Comment: @jcalz Not sure if adding the `embind` tag helps here. It's a pure Typescript question and the documentation of `extend` doesn't explain much. But ok, I can add it.

Comment: @kelsny Meanwhile I found out what `typeof AClass` means. Unfortunately, the TS documentation for `typeof` doesn't mention it: the `typeof` operator applied to a class returns its constructor function, which explains why I could not use the result of `typeof AClass` in places where a simple `AClass` was expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As so often simplified examples for asking a question do not fully represent the real problem at hand. In this case the `Lexer` class is an ambient declaration, used for the WASM module generated by embind.

To use such a class it must be exported from the module (which is an interface) and can only be used once the module is loaded. After that happened the types from the WASM module can be exported.

To use a class like `Lexer` you need two declarations:

```js
let antlr4: ANTLR4Wasm;
try {
    antlr4 = await Module();
} catch (e) {
    throw new Error("Could not initialize the ANTLR4 runtime:\n" + e);
}

type Lexer = InstanceType<typeof antlr4.Lexer>;
const Lexer = antlr4.Lexer;
```

This can be used to export a single identifier:

```js
export { Lexer }:
```

With that in place you can use just `Lexer` as type or as value. TS will take care automatically. This way you can do both:

```
const WhiteboxLexerTrampoline = Lexer.extend<Lexer>("Lexer", {
});
```

(`WhiteboxLexerTrampoline` is of type `Lexer`, not `typeof Lexer` or `() => Lexer`)

and

```
const lexer = new Lexer();
```

For completeness: the `Extendable` class has been changed for better type safety:

```
export declare class Extendable extends Deletable {
    public static extend<T>(name: string, o: { [key in keyof T]?: T[key]; }): Constructor<T>;
}
```

which in turn allows to derive from `WhiteboxLexerTrampoline` or create an instance of it.